# Why is the "else" code block executed for this for loop?

Tags: java

I think I understand the first statement. It's saying, if the items in "words" are NOT in "frequencies", then add them and assign a value of 1 to each, right? 
What I am more confused about is why the "else" block gets executed and how it works. I understand the output, but not quite how it works. It obviously recognizes that a particular word appears more than once but how does it recognize that? And again, why does it go to the "else" block if the first statement is true?

```
public class Testing {

  static List<String> list() {

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    words.add("Cherry");
    words.add("Banana");
    words.add("Apple");
    words.add("Banana");
    words.add("Berry");

    return words;
  }

  static Map<String, Integer> ArrayFrequencies(List<String> words) {

    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String elements : words) {

      if (!frequencies.containsKey(elements)) {
        frequencies.put(elements, 1);
      } else {
        frequencies.put(elements, frequencies.get(elements) + 1);
      }
    }

    return frequencies;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(ArrayFrequencies(list()));
  }
}
```

output : {Apple=1, Cherry=1, Berry=1, Banana=2}

Comment: It gets executed if the key is already in the map. For example, you've got `Banana` in the input twice, so the `else` is executed when the second one is encountered.

Comment: The else clause doesn't get executed if `!frequencies.containsKey(elements)` (note that it is unforunate that the variable is called `elements` instead of `element` because it can cause confusion). You are asking the wrong question.

Comment: Debug it and follow the steps. Your expectation what is executed when may be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is behaving as expected. The else statement is only executed when it needs to(When a given item is already in the list and you only need to increment its count). Here, I wrote some debug messages to your code. Run it and you will see exactly what is going on.

```
package strings;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Testing {

  static List<String> list() {

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    words.add("Cherry");
    words.add("Banana");
    words.add("Apple");
    words.add("Banana");
    words.add("Berry");
    words.add("Banana");
    words.add("Berry");
    words.add("Banana");

    return words;
  }

  static Map<String, Integer> ArrayFrequencies(List<String> words) {

    Map<String, Integer> frequencies = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (String element : words) {

      if (!frequencies.containsKey(element)) {
            System.out.println("Seems like => " + element + "  is not in the list yet. Adding it" );
        frequencies.put(element, 1);
      } else {

           System.out.println("Seems like => " + element + " is in the list already. Incrementing its count from  : " + 
                              frequencies.get(element) + "  => to   : " + (frequencies.get(element) + 1) );
        frequencies.put(element, frequencies.get(element) + 1);
      }
    }

    return frequencies;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(ArrayFrequencies(list()));
  }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Seems like => Cherry  is not in the list yet. Adding it
Seems like => Banana  is not in the list yet. Adding it
Seems like => Apple  is not in the list yet. Adding it
Seems like => Banana is in the list already. Incrementing its count from  : 1  => to   : 2
Seems like => Berry  is not in the list yet. Adding it
Seems like => Banana is in the list already. Incrementing its count from  : 2  => to   : 3
Seems like => Berry is in the list already. Incrementing its count from  : 1  => to   : 2
Seems like => Banana is in the list already. Incrementing its count from  : 3  => to   : 4
{Apple=1, Cherry=1, Berry=2, Banana=4}
```

Comment: Wow thanks alot! This was very very helpful! Thanks for taking the time to create the debug messages. I understand now. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(!frequencies.containsKey(elements))  
    {
        //put the data in map for the first time
        //Suppose Element "Apple" entering for the first time
        frequencies.put(elements, 1); 
    } else {
       //put the data in map if map already contains that element
       //Element "Apple entering for the second time". Here it will get previous count and increase by one
       frequencies.put(elements, frequencies.get(elements) + 1 );
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very helpful. I understand it more now!

Comment: @IGJ If you want , You can mark it as correct .  WC

Answer (score 0):

> What I am more confused about is why the "else" block gets executed and how it works.

The `if` block sets the map entry to 1 explicitly because it's the first value being associated with the `elements` key.

The `else` block is updating the map entry.  It exists, it has a value, and it needs to be incremented.  So you say:

```
frequencies.get(elements) + 1 //get the prior value and add one to it
frequencies.put(^^^^^^^)      //update the map entry with the new value from above.
```

**NOTE**:  You can't apply the logic from the else block to the if, because you can't increment null.

Comment: Thank you!! This was very helpful!